# SPOnline - Follow a site programmatically on behalf of another user

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a site in SharePoint Online that I would like all users in my organization to follow.  I have been trying to use CSOM, Powershell and Rest to achieve that with no success - I can only do that for the current user.
Ideally, I would like the process to run every night and set all new users and users who "un-followed" my site to follow it again. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible as per this documentation:

[Common programming tasks for following content in SharePoint](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/follow-content-in-sharepoint#common-programming-tasks-for-following-content-in-sharepoint)

To quote:

> Create an instance of a manager object in **the context of a specified
>   user**
>
> - CSOM: not implemented
> - JSOM: not implemented
> - REST: not implemented
> - SSOM:  SPSocialFollowingManager (overloaded)

You can only follow for the current user using client-side calls. Unfortunately only SSOM allows managing following for other users.

(With Groups and the Microsoft Graph you are also out of luck as the docs for [addFavorite](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_addfavorite) explicitly states it's for the current user only.)